# Why is the concentration of pure water is 55.5 mol/L?

Tags: water, concentration

Whilst reading about pH, it is given that concentration of water is $\pu{55.5 M}$. Let water be of $\pu{1 mol}$ at $\pu{297 K}$ and $\pu{1 atm}$ pressure. Then the concentration is 
$$c =\frac{n}{v} = \frac{P}{RT}\\
  =\frac{1}{8.314\times 297} = 0.004 $$

But it should be $\pu{55.5 mol/L}$. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: The ideal gas equation (pV=nRT) isn't going to help you here, you're looking at the *concentration* of a liquid.

Comment: You are calculating the concentration of water *vapour* (a gas); your question is about *liquid* water.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you want to work out the number of moles in a litre ($\pu{1000 mL}$) of water: 
\begin{align}
  n &= \frac{m}{M_r}\\[1ex]
    &= \frac{\pu{1000 g}}{\pu{18 g mol-1}}\\
    &= \pu{55.5 mol}\\
\end{align}

We know that the mass of $\pu{1000 mL}$ of water is $\pu{1000 g}$, and the molecular weight of water is around $\pu{18 g mol-1}$, therefore the calculation gives us an answer of $\pu{55.5 mol}$.

This can then be plugged into the equation for concentration:
\begin{align}
  n &= cV\\[1ex]
  c &= \frac{n}{V}\\
  c &= \frac{\pu{55.5 mol}}{\pu{1 dm3}}\\
    &= \pu{55.5 mol dm-3}\\
\end{align}

Since $\pu{1000 mL}$ of water is precisely $\pu{1 dm3}$ (and the units for concentration are in moles per decimetre), the concentration of water is also $\pu{55.5 mol dm-3}$.